# How to create a custom typeahead using angular-formly which should be generic, any suggestions?

Tags: bootstrap-4, autocomplete, angular6, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-formly

I am new to formly, I tried creating typeahead but got stuck. Please help me out in creating typeahead.